# can't open file with browser using act_url

Tags: python, odoo

I'm using ODOO 9, Windows 10 and Chrome.

I'm trying to open file on my disk in new tab of browser, and can't do it (((

Browser opens new tab, but it's blank((

Where's my mistake, could you help me?

My code:

```
def show_my_data(self,cr, uid, ids, arg, context=None):

    return {
        'name': 'Go to website',
        'res_model': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'target': 'new',
        'url': 'file:///D:/tmp.html'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clients cannot access to your D partition Odoo will not allow that.

To make your file accessible put in inside the static folder.

```
      your_module_name
                --->  static
                      ---> tmp.html
```

In your action do this instead

```
      'url': 'you_module_name/static/tmp.html'
```

And it's better to put inside another folder for organizing purpose.

Remember this anything you put inside static folder is public and can be accessed via URL. Every tging else is private and protected.